# SCSS - hsla equivalent of the rgba() function

Tags: css, sass

I am converting some of my color values from scss rgba variables to css custom properties using the hsla color model.

For example,

```
$color-navy: rgba(57, 80, 112, 1);
```

becomes

```
:root {
    --color-navy: hsla(214, 33%, 33%, 1);
}
```

My problem is I use the scss `rgba()` function to add varying degress of opacity to my colors:

```
color: rgba($color-black, 0.87);
```

Is there an hsla equivalent of this where I can pass in my custom property and apply an alpha?

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
hsla(var(--color-black), 0.5)
```

Comment: rgba is not scss related, it is normal css, isn't the `a` in `hsla` alpha? same as rgba's `a`

Comment: Maybe this questions helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589452/using-css-variables-in-hsla-in-scss

Comment: It is also a bit confusing that you used scss var `color: rgba($color-black, 0.87);` and then you used css var here `hsla(var(--color-black), 0.5)`. Please clarify which kind of var you want to use

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330103/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Both rgba and hsla are CSS functions. rgba is not an SCSS function as such.

The 'a' in both stands for alpha channel which basically gives the opacity, 0 or 0% being completely transparent and 1 or 100% being completely opaque.

So taking your example navy color:

rgba(57, 80, 112, 0.4) would be equivalent to hsla(214, 33%, 33%, 0.4)

See for example: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Applying_color`

Comment: I understand, I'm looking for a way to pass in a custom property to the hsla function and apply the alpha to it, like 'hsla(--color-blue, .05)'